# How can I use existing tokens to send out a single Scheduled Reminder to both the Org and the Employee

Tags: tokens

Scenario is:
Acme has a membership which is inherited by employees.
John is a permissioned employee - and hence should be able to renew 'on behalf of' and hence goal is that he should be sent Scheduled Reminders pertaining to the membership (in 4.6)

To be able to use a single reminder that makes sense whether it is sent to the Org or the Employee I need something like:

Regarding membership of {contact.organization_name}{contact.current_employer}

That way the Reminder that goes to the Org, shows its name, and for the one going to the employee it grabs the employers name, and the unsuccessful token will just not show in both cases.

Currently afaik there is no such token for {contact.organization_name}.

Answer (score 3):

We have done this with {membership.owner}, which works for the email that goes to the main contact (with inherited membership) and the organization email.

E.g. TestOrg’s membership is due for renewal //// {membership.owner}’s membership is due for renewal

Answer (score 2):

Okay seems {contact.organization_name} does work, just not listed in dropdown. Will request a fix in JIRA

So I can confirm that 
Regarding membership of {contact.organization_name}{contact.current_employer}

Gives us 'ACME' as the answer when Reminder is sent to both the Org and to the Employee

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16470